# Share code between features in spock framework

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm using spock for test.

For a specification S, I have three distinct features F1, F2, F3.

I have my features with *given*, *when*, *then* part but I want to share the code between *given* and *when* since that's almost the same except for the *then* part

pseudo code:

```
class S extends Specification {

 def 'f1' () {
   given:
     redundantcode('file1')
   then:
     redundantcode_2_with_no_param
   when:
     valuable_code_1
 }

 def 'f2' () {
   given:
     redundantcode('file2')
   then:
     redundantcode_2_with_no_param
   when:
     valuable_code_2
 }

 def 'f3' () {
   given:
     redundantcode('file3')
   then:
     redundantcode_2_with_no_param
   when:
     valuable_code_3
 }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid duplicated code in given and when part.

Comment: It would be good to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of pseudo code. And besides, it is given-when-then, you wrote given-then-when, which makes it even more irritating to find out what you really want to do. Nobody can compile and run your code and then refactor it for you.

Comment: Hey Christof! First you are asking a question and then when people are trying to help you or asking follow-up questions you ignore them? What kind of behaviour is that? Would you like to be treated that way?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was away.  Really sorry.  I'm looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a method in you test class. E.g.:

```
void redundantcode_2_with_no_param() {…}
```

Note that if you use "def" instead of "void", whatever the last line in your method will return, will be returned from the method. That might lead to a failing test, if it is null.

Comment: the idea is more to share all part with given and then part included in one line

Comment: Before you said 'given' and 'when', now it is 'then'? I guess that was just a typo, wasn't it?

Comment: I don't get what you're up to. Can you update your question with some example what you'd like the code to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps looking for a parameterized testing approach using Data Tables or data pipes? [Data Driven Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html)

For example, you could do:

```
def 'f1' () {
 when:
   redundantcode(fileName)
 then: 
   redundantcode_with_no_param
 then: 
   valuable_code_3
 where: 
   fileName << ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
 }
```

This is assuming your valuable_code_3 is somewhat repeatable as well. If you have a comparison somewhere in there you could expand it to have a second value in the where clause of "result << ['expectedResult1', 'expectedResult2', 'expectedResult3'] etc. etc.